# How to rearrange an Ordered Dictionary with a based on part of the key from a list

Tags: python

I am rearranging some Ordered Dictionary based on the key from a list. 
Such in:

```
old_OD = OrderedDict([('cat_1',1), 
            ('dog_1',2), 
            ('cat_2',3),
            ('fish_1',4), 
            ('dog_2',5)])
```

Now I have a list of the group's order.

```
order = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']
```

and get the result with the items in the dictionary grouped together, as such:

```
new_OD = OrderedDict([('dog_1',2),
            ('dog_2',5), 
            ('cat_1',1), 
            ('cat_2',3),
            ('fish_1',4)])
```

I found some excellent related question [How to reorder OD based on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405537/how-to-reorder-a-python-ordered-dict-based-on-array) and [Re-ordering OrderedDict](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86294/reordering-ordereddict?newreg=5ae766f9616e43609f1108cd7c40d3ca) and I am going with the solution in the second link

```
new_od = OrderedDict([(k, None) for k in order if k in old_od])
new_od.update(old_od)
```

Now, in my case, "k" is not exact match and desired key value for the new_od, how should I modify to construct the new od?

EDIT: So what happen if there is no underscore that mark the location of the keyword, like we have "Big_cat_3" or "dog_black_2"? The keyword could be anywhere in the string. Once the key are grouped together, alpha-numerical order is not needed.

Comment: Great first question! I wish all new contributors were like you!

Comment: If the input is `OrderedDict([('dog_2', 2), ('dog_1', 1)])`, would the desired output be `OrderedDict([('dog_1', 1), ('dog_2', 2)])` (sort by number) or `OrderedDict([('dog_2', 2), ('dog_1', 1)])` (maintain the original order)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I am sharing two variants of solution for this.

**1. For keys with same prefix, *keep the order of initial `OrderedDict`***

Here I am using *list comprehension* to iterate the `order` list and `OrderDict`. Based on comparison, we are passing list of tuples with desired order for creating `OrderedDict` object:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> old_OD = OrderedDict([('cat_1',1),
...             ('dog_1',2),
...             ('cat_2',3),
...             ('fish_1',4),
...             ('dog_2',5)])
>>> order = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']

>>> new_OD = OrderedDict([(k,v) for o in order for k, v in old_OD.items() if k.startswith(o+'_')])
#                                              to match the prefix pattern of <key> + "_" ^
```

where `new_OD` will hold:

```
OrderedDict([('dog_1', 2), ('dog_2', 5), ('cat_1', 1), ('cat_2', 3), ('fish_1', 4)])
```

**2. For keys with same prefix, *perform [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) sorting of elements***

We may modify the above solution using `sorted` and `itertools.chain` with nested *list comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> new_OD = OrderedDict(chain(*[sorted([(k,v) for k, v in old_OD.items() if k.startswith(o+'_')]) for o in order]))
```

where `new_OD` will hold:

```
OrderedDict([('dog_1', 2), ('dog_2', 5), ('cat_1', 1), ('cat_2', 3), ('fish_1', 4)])
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't sort the keys by the numbers, though. (For example, an input of `{'dog_2': 5, 'dog_1': 2}` would not change at all.) Not sure if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @Aran-Fey It is ok if it is not sorted in numerical or alphabetical order, as long as it is in group.

Comment: @Aran-Fey It was a fair point. I added the variant of the solution with lexicographical sorting

Comment: @Bogdan Please add that piece of information to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a dict that maps each item in `order` to its index, and then use the `sorted` function with a key function that maps the substring of the each key in `old_OD` that appears in the keys of the mapping dict to the corresponding index using the mapping dict:

```
keys = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(order)}
OrderedDict(sorted(old_OD.items(), key=lambda t: keys.get(next(i for i in t[0].split('_') if i in keys))))
```

This returns:

```
OrderedDict([('dog_1', 2), ('dog_2', 5), ('cat_1', 1), ('cat_2', 3), ('fish_1', 4)])
```

Comment: So what happen if there is no underscore that mark the location of the keyword, like we have "Big_cat_3" or "dog_black_2"? The keyword could be anywhere in the string. Thanks!

Comment: I see. I've updated both of my answers accordingly then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `groupby()` with a sorted dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import groupby, chain
from operator import itemgetter

ld_OD = OrderedDict([('cat_1',1), 
    ('dog_1',2), 
    ('cat_2',3),
    ('fish_1',4), 
    ('dog_2',5)])

order = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']

gb = groupby(sorted(ld_OD.items()), key=lambda t: t[0].split('_')[0])
gb = {k: list(g) for k, g in gb}
OrderedDict(chain.from_iterable(itemgetter(*order)(gb)))
# OrderedDict([('dog_1', 2), ('dog_2', 5), ('cat_1', 1), ('cat_2', 3), ('fish_1', 4)])
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient approach to solve this problem in a time complexity of *O(n)* (instead of *O(n log n)* with sorting) is to build a dict that maps the substring of each key that appears in `order` (which should be converted to a set for efficient lookups) to a list of belonging key-value pairs from `old_OD`, and then build the new `OrderedDict` by iterating an index through a range of the length of `order` and output to the `OrderedDict` constructor the values in the mapping dict keyed by the value of `order` at the index:

```
keys = set(order)
mapping = {}
for k, v in old_OD.items():
    mapping.setdefault(next(i for i in k.split('_') if i in keys), []).append((k, v))
OrderedDict(t for i in range(len(order)) for t in mapping[order[i]])
```

This returns:

```
OrderedDict([('dog_1', 2), ('dog_2', 5), ('cat_1', 1), ('cat_2', 3), ('fish_1', 4)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `regex` and `partial` functions.

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter
from functools import partial

first = itemgetter(0)
pattern = '|'.join(order) # 'dog|cat|fish'

def group(order, pattern, txt):
    item = first(txt)
    res = re.search(pattern, item)
    return order.index(res.group(0))

p = partial(group, order, pattern)

OrderedDict(sorted(old_OD.items(), key=p))

OrderedDict([('dog_1', 2),
             ('dog_2', 5),
             ('cat_1', 1),
             ('cat_2', 3),
             ('fish_1', 4)])
```